# Background image bottom-right alignment error - chrome on android

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, background-image

I have a website that requires a 'bottom right' background image alignment, along with a background colour of #000.

My css tests okay on all OS and browsers I've tried so far (chrome, ie, moz, safari) except for chrome on android, which renders the background image outside the browser window.
Other image alignments work fine - the problem seems to be *only* with bottom right alignment, and *only* with chrome on android.

Problem page url: [Features a background-image: bottom right alignment](http://m233933.000webhostapp.com/prices.html)

CSS as follows:

```
body { 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    background: url("../images/bg_prices_XL.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-color: #000;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom right; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

If I change alignment to background-image: top right; then the problem goes away.

Page renders properly on android moz. Do I therefore need to include a -webkit specific alignment?

Havd tried adding:

```
html,body {
   height 100%;
   width 100%;
}
```

...but no luck. Viewport size already set to device size, Chrome seemingly is rendering oitside the viewport anyway, below the footer.

Tried styling the background-image under html section of css, but didn't work.

All thoughts welcome.

Comment: "pc and ios" ...

Comment: Apologies - to clarify, this should read 'site tests okay on all browsers and  OS platforms I've tried to date, except chrome on android'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have inspected the page throught chrome dev tools. I think if you remove background-attachment: fixed; propery it will work. [image]

Comment: Thx - but will this deactivate fixed image scrolling on other browsers and platforms? Apparently this is a bug in android going back eight years. See: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36908439

Answer (score 0):

...never mind folks. I made the background a fixed, 100% height and width div, with a negative z-index. It feels like a clunky workaround to me, but it seems to work. Any better suggestions though would be appreciated thank you.